# KNN find nearest error

Tags: opencv, machine-learning

I'm doing KNN classification of static gestures and i get this error.

> ERROR: Unhandled exception at 0x01213aa2 in NUIGHR.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

```
CvMat* GetFeatures(CvSeq* contour, CvSeq* hull, double boundingRectArea){
CvMoments moments;
CvHuMoments humoments;
cvMoments(contour, &moments, cvGetHuMoments(&moments, &humoments);

int cCont;
double cArea, cPerimeter, cDiameter, cExtent, cCompactness, cEccentricity, cCircularity;

cCont         = contour->total;
cArea         = fabs(cvContourArea(contour));
cPerimeter    = cvContourPerimeter(contour);
cDiameter     = sqrt( 4 * cArea / CV_PI);
cExtent       = cArea / (boundingRectArea * boundingRectArea);
cCompactness  = (4 * cArea * CV_PI) / cPerimeter;
cEccentricity = pow( (moments.m20 - moments.m02), 2) - (4 * pow(moments.m11, 2)) / ( pow(moments.m20 + moments.m02, 2) );
cCircularity = pow(cPerimeter, 2) / cArea;

cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 0,  boundingRectArea);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 1,  cCont);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 2,  cArea);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 3,  cPerimeter);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 4,  cDiameter);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 5,  cExtent);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 6,  cCompactness);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 7,  cEccentricity);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 8,  cCircularity);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 9,  humoments.hu1);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 10, humoments.hu2);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 11, humoments.hu3);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 12, humoments.hu4);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 13, humoments.hu5);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 14, humoments.hu6);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 15, humoments.hu7);

return featureVector;
}
int main(){
...
const int K = 10;
CvKNearest *knn = NULL;
float resultNode = 0;
CvMat* featVector = cvCreateMat(1, NUMBER_OF_FEATURES, CV_32FC1 );
CvMat* nearest = cvCreateMat(1, K, CV_32FC1);
...
resultNode = knn->find_nearest(&featVector, K, 0, 0, nearest, 0);
}
```

I think i need to convert CvMat* to CvMat.
How do i do it?

Comment: Is that all your code for `featVector`?

Comment: CvMat* featVector = cvCreateMat(1, NUMBER_OF_FEATURES, CV_32FC1 );cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 0,  humoments.hu1);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 1, humoments.hu2);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 2, humoments.hu3);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 3, humoments.hu4);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 4, humoments.hu5);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 5, humoments.hu6);
cvmSet( featureVector, 0, 6, humoments.hu7);thanks

Comment: Aren't you missing an argument? According to the [doc](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/k_nearest_neighbors.html#cvknearest-find-nearest), since you are using dist, shouldn't you have 6 arguments? Otherwise neighbor_responses = dist and dist = 0

Comment: Also, you should edit your answer to include the extra code you wrote in the comments so that you make it easier for people to respond :)

Comment: think that is enough for you guys. You're right sorry.

Comment: 0xC0000005 reminds me when ppl use `cvLoadImage()` and forget to check if the result is valid. Passing the result (usually a NULL ptr) to the next CV function will crash the app with code 0xC0000005 on Windows. You might have a NULL pointer somewhere. Always check the success of the functions. The debugger will tell you what line caused the crash, so what is the offending line?

Comment: i can print out the featureVector at main just before resultNode = knn->find_nearest(&featVector, K, 0, 0, nearest, 0); thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass 0 as 3rd and 4th argument to find_nearest function, not if you do pass something as 5th argument. OpenCV tries to populate the results and neighbourResponses ([see doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html?highlight=find_nearest#cv2.KNearest.find_nearest)), but cannot read/write the NULL pointer.

Comment: i made it diferent but same error.                                          resultNode = knn->find_nearest(&test_sample, K, 0, 0, resp, 0);

Comment: @user Sorry, but if you don't show us your code, we cannot help you. We can't guess what your variables (`test_sample`, `K`, `resp`, `dist` etc ) are. Please edit your question to include all the relative code.

Comment: as I said, you MUST NOT pass 0 as arguments to resultNode = knn->find_nearest(&featVector, K, 0, 0, nearest, 0); but you must pass well initialised, expected arguments, see the doc.

Answer (score 0):

featureVector = NULL pointer
sorry guys... i'm a beginner :(